# Is it valid to have an HTML form inside of a 'section' tag?

Tags: html, forms

Is it valid to have an HTML form inside of a 'section' tag?

My professor keeps using section tags out the wazoo and I don't think he's always using them appropriately.  Wanted to check on this specific instance.

Comment: do you have any references why you don't believe him? what does his code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is valid.

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element) says that it can contain any flow content, where [flow content is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content):

> Most elements that are used in the body of documents and applications are categorized as flow content.
>
> a abbr address area (if it is a descendant of a map element) article aside audio b bdi bdo blockquote br button canvas cite code command datalist del details dfn div dl em embed fieldset figure footer **form** h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 header hgroup hr i iframe img input ins kbd keygen label map mark math menu meter nav noscript object ol output p pre progress q ruby s samp script section select small span strong style (if the scoped attribute is present) sub sup svg table textarea time u ul var video wbr text

If was still irking you, you could point him to this note:

> The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.

Comment: Right, but I thought that the 'section' elements should almost always contain a heading? Since the form is the only thing he has on the page other than the actual 'header' section. It seems a little bit out of place to me. I would think syntax-wise it is irrelevant to use the section tag (in this case) whether or not it is valid HTML.